# RecyclerView scroll position not getting saved automatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Update:

Polishing the last bits of the app i tried to solve this issue, turns out that the solution is setting up the adapter like stated in the article mentioned in the post.

`adapter.stateRestorationPolicy = PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY`

I Thought i tried that but apparently if i did it i just did it the wrong way because now its working just fine.

I hope this helps to someone with a similiar problem than mine

I'm experiencing a weird problem and I can't find a solution because of my inexperience. First of all the app I'm working on has 3 fragments and the 3 of them display a RecyclerView. The problem I have is that 2 of the 3 fragment save the scrolling of the recyclerView when I switch orientation, but one of them doesn't, and is driving me crazy because the structure of the 3 is exactly the same.

As stated here: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/restore-recyclerview-scroll-position-a8fbdc9a9334 the recycler view position should be restored automatically and it does in 2 of my 3 fragments even without setting the stateRestorationPolicy.

The fragment I have the problem with is this one:

```kotlin
class WorkoutLogFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: WorkoutLogVieModel by viewModels { GymTrackerViewModelFactory}

    private var _binding: FragmentWorkoutLogBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private val navigationArgs: WorkoutLogFragmentArgs by navArgs()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentWorkoutLogBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        /* setting up the topAppBar */
        val navController = findNavController()
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
        binding.topAppBar.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)


        /* setting up the recyclerView */
        val adapter = WorkoutLogListAdapter()
        binding.apply {
            logsRV.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@WorkoutLogFragment.context)
            logsRV.adapter = adapter
        }

        /* coroutine to collect list of exercises */
       viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch{
           viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED){
               viewModel.exerciseListFromWorkout(navigationArgs.workoutId).collect{
                   adapter.submitList(it.exercises)
               }
           }
       }

        binding.topAppBar.setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem ->
            when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.addExercise -> {
                    val action = WorkoutLogFragmentDirections.actionWorkoutLogFragmentToExerciseListFragment(
                        workoutId = navigationArgs.workoutId
                    )
                    navController.navigate(action)
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }

    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

and its xml file is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.WorkoutLogFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarWorkoutLog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:menu="@menu/top_app_bar_workout_log"
            app:titleCentered="true"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_close_24dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- Note: A RecyclerView can also be used -->
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/logsNestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <!-- Scrollable content -->

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/logsRV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As you can see in the code every view has its own id which is mandatory for the RecyclerView to be able to save the scroll position. I tried to set the adapterRestorationPolicy to:

`adapter.stateRestorationPolicy = PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY`
and doesn't work at all, I tried to fill the adapter data before setting it to the RecyclerView,
also tried to save the scrolling state in the viewmodel, in onSavedIntanceSate and recovering it onCreate and nothing seems to work.

The only thing that works is forcing the app to not destroy the fragment on rotation, but I don't want to do that.

Obviously there is a problem somewhere but as I stated before because of my inexperience I can't figure out where is this problem coming from.

Thank you for your time.